# Insert xml in target and after everysingle sucessful save that filename in another table

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

Please if you can you do it image. I would like to improve my knowledge

https://imgur.com/a/6fuYoo9

i'm loading data from xml to tables (Targets 7 or 7 tables)
after loaded everysingle xml can be sucessful or fail. So i want to save that filename it was sucessful or not in another catalog table or target colled filesdescription etc.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wAGJ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In your Source Properties - Fields check `Add Currently Processed Filename field`

Based on additional logic in your mapping about the load is success or fail you can insert this field to another table or audit purposes.